# Phonegap build for Polymer 3.0 PWA Starter Kit

Tags: polymer, phonegap, polymer-3.x

I've tried to build polymer-pwa-kit with phonegap.

https://github.com/PolymerLabs/books

every thing is fine on browsers.

but after polymer build,

a) with default codes;
webcomponent tag not working and it did not render polymer dom.

b) if it removes base tag in index.html then,
it routed 404 page and rendered fine.

these are on the phonegap developer app.

anybody polymer 3.0 and phonegap build to success?

Comment: Try `<base href="/">` instead  `<base href="./">`  at phonegap copy.

Comment: it already used it. :(